# Calling without using UI

Tags: android, phone-call

Is there a way to call a contact without showing a UI that allows the user to initiate a call? So when I click on a button, the contact number is immediately dialed like when I go to the last calls in my phone an click on someone, they are immediately called.

The code I am using right now is:

```
try {
   Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.CALL_ACTION);
   intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + number));
   startActivity(intent);
} catch (Exception e) {
   Log.e("SampleApp", "Failed to invoke call", e);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add a permission `android.permission.CALL_PHONE` to the manifest and change `Intent.CALL_ACTION` to `Intent.ACTION_CALL`

Comment: I accept this answer because this was the first one, but all the three answers are correct. ACTION_CALL works and ACTION_DIAL doesn't. Thanks!

Comment: request `android.permission.CALL_PHONE` in runtime? what exactly does't work?

Answer (score 2):

Code you are posted should not work...
there is no CALL_ACTION, use ACTION_CALL instead.

Comment: I'm using sg like that, the code i copy-pasted from the net was wrong, but that is not question right now :) The code im using (i am not at home, so i couldn't post my code) is working fine.

Comment: So, you should get number dialed. Isn't it your problem - "Note: this Intent cannot be used to call emergency numbers. Applications can dial emergency numbers using ACTION_DIAL, however."

Answer (score 1):

```
private void call() {    
    try {    
        Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);    
        callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:123456789"));    
        startActivity(callIntent);    
    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e)        {    
         Log.e("helloandroid dialing example", "Call failed", e);    
    }
```

***AndroidManifest.xml***

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"></uses-permission>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.CALL_ACTION);
```

should be

```
  Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
```

This is my complete code:

```
    Intent intentcall = new Intent();
    intentcall.setAction(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
    intentcall.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + phoneNumber)); 
    startActivity(intentcall);
```